# EnumSet 'and' operation

Tags: java, enums

I'm porting some old code that uses the [int enum pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) to Enum and EnumSet. It is very easy but I don't know how translate the following code to EnumSet: :

```
int mask = (kind == 'C' ? CLASS_MODIFIERS
            : kind == 'F' ? FIELD_MODIFIERS
            : kind == 'M' ? METHOD_MODIFIERS
            : (CLASS_MODIFIERS | FIELD_MODIFIERS | METHOD_MODIFIERS));
int bad_flags = flags & ~mask; // <--- this
flags &= mask; // <--- and this
```

`~mask` is simple as typing `EnumSet.complementOf` but I don't see how do **&**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `Set` method [retainAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) to get the intersection of two sets:

```
public class Test {
  public enum Kind { CLASS, FIELD, METHOD }

  public void applyMask(char kind, EnumSet<Kind> flags) {
    final EnumSet<Kind> mask;
    switch (kind) {
      case 'C': mask = EnumSet.of(Kind.CLASS);    break;
      case 'F': mask = EnumSet.of(Kind.FIELD);    break;
      case 'M': mask = EnumSet.of(Kind.METHOD);   break;
      default:  mask = EnumSet.allOf(Kind.class); break;
    }
    EnumSet<Kind> badFlags = EnumSet.copyOf(flags);
    badFlags.removeAll(mask); // See note below
    flags.retainAll(mask);
  }
}
```

Note: I previously had the following line in place of the simpler `removeAll`.  Tom Hawtin pointed out that `removeAll` is simpler and achieves the same end.  Originally, I just copied the OP's original logic as closely as possible, without trying to optimize.

```
    badFlags.retainAll(EnumSet.complementOf(mask));
```

Comment: I think removeAll would be more obvious than emulating the bit-twiddling retainAll complementOf.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: True.  I was emulating the previous logic, but you're right.  removeAll would be more, well, logical in this position.

Answer (score -2):

`CLASS_MODIFIERS`, `FIELD_MODIFIERS`, and `METHOD_MODIFIERS` might be appropriate to leave as constants, since they are being used as [bit masks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask).  The link might help to clarify the point of this code.

Comment: The whole point of this post is to switch from bit masks to enums/enumsets